# Angularjs send mails

Tags: javascript, jquery, javascript-framework, email, angularjs

I started to use AngularJs and I really love it, and just discoverd this pluging for angular -> https://github.com/witoldsz/angular-http-auth, that lets you implement a identification system.

Anyone know a resource like the one I mentioned for easy send emails ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll have to implement sending emails on your server. Alternatively, there are some paid services like [Postmark](http://developer.postmarkapp.com/) that give you a JSON API that would be easy to hook into AngularJS to send emails.

Comment: Perfect !! Thx alot. What you recomend me more for start nodejs or ruby raisl for server side ???

Comment: I think that both are great. :) I'm personally a fan of node.js, and unless you already know Ruby, node.js will probably be a more gentile learning curve since you already know (or are learning) JavaScript.

Comment: anyone know how to comunicate angualrjs with nodejs for sned emails ??

Comment: You should make your own questions with this, but basically you'd send some fields via angularjs to some nodejs route that gets the params and send the mail. npm search mail should help you